# Angular - upload file when file is chosen (native implementation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to create an 'attach' button as in gmail that when clicking on it, a browse window will open, and upon a user choice, an http request will be sent to the server.

Today I'm using the following code in the client:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="data" />
                        <input type="submit">do it</input>
</form>
```

This is not good for a couple of reasons:

1. I do not want a submit button to send the files to the server, I want it to be triggered when 
   the file is chosen by the user.
2. The form default action behavior is to send the user to a different page

I'm looking for an implementation (native angular code, not an external library) of an http post request with the same details (`enctype="multipart/form-data"` and the file details) but without using a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is this the `native` that you talked about or not, but I use this in my projects:

```
$scope.form = null;
$scope.uploaded = [];

$scope.upload = function(){
  var data = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem('form')); // form name
  $http.post('/upload', data, {                              // change with your endpoint
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  })
  .success(function(res){
    $scope.uploaded.push(res);
    $scope.form = null;
  });
};

$scope.$watch('form', function(){
  $scope.upload();
});
```

HTML*:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in uploaded">
  {{n.filename}}
</div>

<form name="form">
  <input type="file" name="data" ng-model="form" />
</form>
```

*Hide your input filename with your css to create a Gmail's like upload. Make sure your server returned a file name or something that you needs here, I assumed that your server returned a file name with key "filename", look at $scope.uploaded above.

Remember to check your server side, that input `file` will be sent with `multipart/form-data` and use `data` as it's name. This will trigger each time user add an image/ file, be careful about handling this kind of thing in your server side. I actually preferred using `submit` button as usual.

Comment: Actually i'll be happy to get the code to handle when the file is chosen.

Comment: I'm using this code which does not run properly:

<input type="file" name="data" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload()"/>

Comment: First of all thanks but this does not quite answer my question... I want to that with a single button of my own which will open a browse dialog... similar to the gmail attach button

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. So you need to open native file picker and then immediately start uploading if user pick a file? I can provide that example but not now, maybe tomorrow because it's late night here 23 PM. I need to go home, lol. Or I hope someone else will help you with that sooner.

Comment: Exactly what I need. also support for multiple files upload. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @omerbach is my already edited answer get it to the right thing that you need? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i used in my project may be it help you.

HTML:

```
<form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitCuisine()" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="description">Image</label> 
               <input type="file"  file-input="files" name="file"/>
            </div>  
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submitCuisine=function(){

        var fd=new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
            fd.append('file',file);
        })
        $http.post('admin/managecuisineAdd',fd,{
            transformRequest:angular.identity,
            headers:{'Content-type':undefined}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.message="Successfully"
        });

}
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive("fileInput",['$parse',function($parse){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('change',function(){
                $parse(attrs.fileInput).
                assign(scope,ele[0].files)
                scope.$apply()
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```